# Use arrays by default instead of ArrayLists in Jackson's ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

By default, Jackson's ObjectMapper de-serialises unknown lists as ArrayList, can it be made to use String[] instead?

```
class SomeBean {
  Object[] items;
}
```

For example, this JSON results in the type of items[0] being ArrayList:

```
{"items":[["a", "b"]]}
```

Comment: Why not using a `toArray` after deserialization ?

Comment: @Valentin - because in actual use the beans are more complicated and I don't want to have to walk the entire object tree looking for ArrayLists.

Answer (score 2):

Not currently, although if you would like to see such feature, you could suggest it by creating a feature request at Jackson JIRA (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON). Implementation should be rather simple; enabled by something like 'DeserializationConfig.Feature.JSON_ARRAYS_AS_JAVA_ARRAYS' (or whatever).

I assume here that you would like to see an Object[], since it can not be guaranteed that contents are all Strings (could have Numbers, Strings, Booleans, lists/maps etc).

Comment: If they are all Strings, I would like to see a String[].

Comment: Right, it's just that this can not be determined in streaming manner; so it will either need to be declared by caller, or done with post-processing (possibly by buffering all elements to see what their types are). If this was done, though, it could be used to create String[], Number[] etc. Not sure how widely useful that would be, but possible certainly.